# Is Multiple Integration Over Random Variables NP HARD

Tags: integration, computational-complexity, machine-learning, np-complete, maximum-likelihood

In a seminar, in a passing moment a presenter mentioned that multiple integrals over random variables is NP-Hard. This means there is no efficient algorithm to compute the integral.

So

> Theorem: Integral of p(x1, x2, x3,...,xn) over x1, x2, ...., xn is np
>   hard.

A preliminary search over the internet didn't give anything to see.

My question is:

1. Is it correct? It looks like correct because in many machine learning models they say that estimating max likelihood over latent variables is np-hard, so can't do it, but I don't really feel confident asserting this.
2. How to go about proving (showing the operation to be of exponential complexity) or disproving the result?
3. Are there tractable or intractable probability distributions too? What do they imply?

Answer (score 0):

1.Yes, it is correct .

2.Here is a sketch. Think of a simple subset of problem instances - binary (0/1) random vars (so the integral become a sum) .What we want to show is that ,given access to some oracle P, with the property that it returns for any n binary values $x_{1}, x_{2},...,x_{n}$ , in time at most polynomial in n, a value from the interval $[0,1]$ , it is NP-hard to compute the (partial) sums over subsets of variables. For these instances we can construct a reduction from SAT. Checking the satisfiability for fixed values of the variables in a formula can be done in polynomial time . We will use such an algorithm as the oracle. Assuming we have an efficient procedure to compute the partial sums , given the oracle , we can use it to efficiently decide the SAT problem : if the total sum is greater then 1, the answer is "yes" , otherwise the answer is "no")

3.Yes, some instances are easy, but in most practical settings one needs to rest on approximations (like Monte Carlo or variational methods  )